# Does Mysql ON condition inside join needs to be binded/escaped?

Tags: mysql, security, join, sql-injection

I use framework that uses custom code to create sql queries. But it seems it doesn't have option to bind param inside ON condition. Part of my query looks like this:

```
LEFT JOIN pages ON pages.page_id = notcountries.page_id AND notcountries.country_id='$countryId'
```

What potential injections could appear inside $countryId if $countryId is retrieved from ajax call? Do you think it is enough to just escape `'` character?

Comment: Are you sure that this cannot be bound??

Comment: I couldn't find a way in Magento which uses Zend framework. It is easy to bound inside where condition, but haven't found anything about bounding inside join condition.

Comment: I don't know magento, but does this help: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10359/left-join-a-table-on-a-collection-query

Comment: I found a way. zend function [quoteInto()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.quoting.quote-into) can be used for that.